# Difference between [[ $variable ]] and [[ -n $variable ]]?

Tags: bash, shell, test

In bash, are `[[ $variable ]]` and `[[ -n $variable ]]` completely equivalent? It appears to be the case judging by the output below, but I see both forms of usage prevalent in shell scripts.

```
$ z="abra"
$ [[ $z ]]
$ echo $?
0
$ [[ -n $z ]]
$ echo $?
0
$ z=""
$ [[ $z ]]
$ echo $?
1
$ [[ -n $z ]]
$ echo $?
1
$ unset z
$ [[ $z ]]
$ echo $?
1
$ [[ -n $z ]]
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Hm. Interesting. Outputs from `[[ -n $(echo -ne "\0") ]]; echo $?` and `[ -n $(echo -ne "\0") ]; echo $?` differ

Comment: @dchirikov, that's because in the second one, you forgot to quote the command substitution, so it ended up being `[ -n ]`, the same `[ -n -n ]`. In shells other than zsh, command (even builtin) arguments or shell variables can't contain NUL characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[ "$var" ]` is equivalent to `[ -n "$var" ]` in bash and most shells nowadays. In other older shells, they're meant to be equivalent, but [suffer from different bugs](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/test/) for some special values of "$var" like `=`, `(` or `!`.

I find `[ -n "$var" ]` more legible and is the pendant of `[ -z "$var" ]`.

`[[ -n $var ]]` is the same as `[[ $var ]]` in all the shells where that non-standard ksh syntax is implemented.

`test "x$var" != x` would be the most reliable if you want to be portable to very old shells.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Test for non-zero length string in bash: [ -n “$var” ] or [ “$var” ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870055/677022), yes, they are equivalent.

They are equivalent even quoting the name of the variable.

*Important to notice*: the name of the question I cite refers only to `[`, but the answer considers both `[` and `[[`.

Comment: But `[[]]` is not the equivalent of `[]` :)

Comment: No, they aren't. But in the answer I cite, both forms are considered.

Comment: Behaviour in testing "\0" as a variable is different. Operator [] gives 0 or 1. And [[]] gives 1 in both cases.

Comment: +1 for the link which is very informative however Stephane Chazelas's answer, which I accepted, is more to the point.